# Click on search bar icon in navigation bar to activate search bar in navigation bar using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, events, search, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

I have tried giving an icon in navigation bar and giving a click event for that icon . And on clicking the icon i created a new search bar in cs file but it is not working

```
<TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="search.png"
                     Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"
                     Order="Primary"/>
 </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>

private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchBar searchBar = new SearchBar { Placeholder = "Search items..."};

        }
```

Comment: Instead of creating searchbar, why don't you manage visibility/ Enabled property of serach bar on click event

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

While I second the comment that it'd be better to add the search bar in XAML and then update the visibility, I'd like to answer the question, because it's rooted in a common misconception of unexperienced devs.

With

```cs
private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchBar searchBar = new SearchBar { Placeholder = "Search items..."};
}
```

you **create an instance** of the `SearchBar` class. Anyway, this does not mean that it's automatically added to the current page. While it might be possible somehow - at least technically - to add the instance to the current page by determining the page that is on top of the current navigation stack it's not really desirable for several reasons

- It's unintuitive from a OOP stand point
- You might want to prepare views and add them later
- You might want to add views to a different page
- It's not even clear *where* to add the view in the current page. Usually there are multiple places a view can be added.
- ...

Instead, you'd have to add the `SearchBar` to your page *explicitly*. How exactly depends on your page layout, but assuming that you have a `StackLayout`

```xml
<StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout">
<!-- ... -->
</StackLayout>
```

you can add the `SearchBar` with

```cs
SearchBar searchBar = new SearchBar { Placeholder = "Search items..."};
StackLayout.Children.Add(searchBar);
```

**Please note** that this will add the `SearchBar` at the end of the `StackLayout`. Presumably, you would like to add it at the top, which you can achieve with

```cs
StackLayout.Children.Insert(0, searchBar); // insert searchBar at index 0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve this,you could look at [TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar), you just need to add the `SearchBar` to your NavigationBar's `TitleView`.

use like below :

```
private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchBar searchBar = new SearchBar { Placeholder = "Search items..." };
        NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, searchBar);

    }
```